# ui-dialog open event executed from a .net mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

If I want to use a jquery dialog in order to display an error message submited from a .net mvc controller action, what I have to do? could you give me an example?

thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: that's great news.  Now could you please mark this as the correct answer by clicking on the tick.  That was the next person knows the answer to your question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the controller i'd be setting a value of a hidden field and checking that with jquery and if you find that you need to show it then show it and reset the hidden field value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var showDlg = $('#myHiddenField').val();
  if (showDlg != "")
    //show dialog
});
```

Don't forget that the value needs to be part of the model you pass back to the view.  For this you would need to implement a FormViewModel I think.

Comment: thanks a lot griegs. I followed your directions and I got the solution.